# How do disable drawing to colour buffer

Tags: opengl

I would like to only write to the Z and Stencil buffers. How do i disable the colour buffer?

Comment: Other questions related to this [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702984/pre-z-buffer-pass-with-opengl)
[link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602647/how-to-write-to-the-opengl-depth-buffer)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`glColorMask`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorMask.xml) with `GL_FALSE` for all the channels.